# Android Java execute function every second in background

Tags: java, android

Hello i want to run a function every second in the background.
So after clicking a button in the app a counter would go and every second  it would get + 1 and if i would switch to another app and get back it should have still been counting in the background.

How do i do this

Alarmmanager?
Handler?

what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

few months back..
I had researched on this and i have found this

-Alarm Manager save more battery than using handler+wakelock. But it is a matter of *timing period*..

**Implementation:**

*UpdateCountInSecond.java*

```
public class UpdateCountInSecond extends Service {
   int count=0

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //your work 
         count++;
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }    
}
```

make a method name: *startServiceAlaramManager()* and call it from your main activity or probably your splash screen

```
public void startServiceAlaramManager(){
        // Start service using AlarmManager

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateCountInSecond .class);

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //1 sec =1000 miliseconds
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000, pintent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "alaram manager set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        startService(new Intent(this, UpdateCountInSecond .class));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TimerTask along with a service.
Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Here, is an example using scheduleAtFixedAtFixedRate(...) function:

```
int counter=0;
Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              counter++;
              //Your code here
        },
        1000, //delay from start in milli seconds
        1000  //update interval in milli seconds
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To throw another option into the mix, try [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Create a runnable and use `scheduleAtFixedRate()`. I'm away from my Dev computer over Christmas so can't check if this'll still work while the app is backgrounded. There's a code example in the above link.